# FlexSlider and Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, flexslider

i'll try to build a slider with FlexSlider
the images in the slider should be viewed 'onclick' with Fancybox.

my code for now:

```
$(".slides li").fancybox();

$('#flex1').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   animationLoop: false,
   itemWidth: 179,
   itemMargin: 0,
   minItems: 4,
   maxItems: 4,
   controlNav: false, 
   pauseOnHover: true,
   slideshowSpeed: 5000,
   keyboardNav: true,
   slideshow: false,
});
```

in document ready

the HTML / PHP looks like this:

```
<div class="flexslider" id="flex1">
    <ul class="slides home_single_item">
       <?php 
            $handle=opendir ("pics/");
            $i=0;
            while ($datei = readdir ($handle)) {
                $i++;
                if($datei != "." && $datei != ".."){
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo '<img class="fancybox" src="pics/'.$datei.'" width="179px" height="224px" />';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }

            closedir($handle);
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If i click on a image, it where displayed as an small picture and it disappears from my gallery list.
Are there any issues known between Flexslider and Fancybox ?
Anyone has a solution ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not conflict or whatsoever.

What you are doing is binding fancybox to the *list* element

```
$(".slides li").fancybox();
```

...so fancybox moves the content of `li` (the `img` tag) to the box. Since you have these properties in your `img` tag:

```
width="179px" height="224px"
```

... the image is small in fancybox.

At this point, fancybox is handling the content as `inline` content so the `img` tag is returned after closing fancybox with the css property `display: none;` (that is the expected behavior.)

What you have to do is to change this part of your php and add an `a` tag to target the image to be opened in fancybox like :

```
if($datei != "." && $datei != ".."){
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="pics/'.$datei.'" class="fancybox">';
    echo '<img src="pics/'.$datei.'" width="179px" height="224px" />';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

... **notice** that we moved the `class="fancybox"` from the `img` tag to the `a` tag. Then bind fancybox to that `a` tag in your script like :

```
$(".slides a").fancybox();
```

or better

```
$(".slides a.fancybox").fancybox();
```

or much simpler and better

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox();
```