# Flexslider carousel / Fancybox images disappearing

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, flexslider

I have a flexslider carousel setup with a link around each image to launch in fancybox with the following code:

```
<div class="flexslider">
   <ul class="slides">
      <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
         <li>
            <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" rel="gallery">
               <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
            </a>
         </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
         animation: "slide",
         animationLoop: true,
         itemWidth: 135,
         itemMargin: 0,
         minItems: 5,
         maxItems: 5,
         directionNav: true,
         controlNav: false,
         slideshow: false
      });
   });
   $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
      helpers : {
         overlay : {
            locked : false
         }
      }
   });
</script>
```

The lightbox loads correctly and carousel functions fine, but when closing the lightbox in Firefox, all of the list items (or images) get hidden until clicked on again. It works fine in Chrome from what I can tell. Any thoughts?

Comment: why don't you try wrapping both initializations inside the `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @JFK Thanks for the reply but sadly that hasn't worked. It might be worth me mentioning that if I move the carousel on one step or make any css adjustment in firebug, all the images reappear.

Comment: then you must have some other settings affecting fancybox not refelcted in your code above. Similar scenarios have been solved in the past (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14247879/1055987) so I don't believe there is a conflict but a localized issue. Can you share a link or jsfiddle with the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding the following:

```
.flexslider .slides li {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```